# Bias on many variables

Tags: bias, weighted-data

**Question**:  How to weight a sample to remove bias that is seen on many variables?

**Background**: I've got two samples which are not random. For every individual I've got three categorical characteristics (A, B, C) and one continuous (X). I want to test whether the difference in average X in both samples is statistically significant. Those samples differ in characteristics A, B, C which are known to have influence on X. My idea is to give some weight to every individual in such a way that weighted distribution of characteristics A, B, C in both samples are the same and then compared weighted average. The question is how to calculate the weights? I could define a loss function that tells how different the characteristics in samples are and use some optimisation method to minimize this loss function (maybe stochastic gradient descent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic solution is called direct standardization, see e.g. Chapter 2 of Donald Treiman (2009) Quantitative Data Analysis: Doing Social Research to Test Ideas. San Francisco: Jossey-Bass.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I don't have this book, but I've made some googling. Description that I found (http://metodykv.wz.cz/QDA2_Standardization.ppt) shows how to remove it if we look only by one characteristic. Does this book contain algorithm that deals with multiple characteristics?

Comment: Yes, see example 2 in that chapter. You can also look at other textbooks. I would start with looking at textbooks on demographics or in the biomedical area, as there this technique is still used.

Comment: I've found some example in internet that deals with more than one characteristic. Is the whole idea more or less as follows: Make direct standarization according to interaction of all characteristics? If we have 3 characteristic and each of them have 3 levels then we divide population into 27 stratums and do direct standarization. Is that the idea behind that?

Comment: yes, it is an old technique, so very simple. (Neither characteristic has a negative connotation to me)

Comment: I didn't know this name although it was my first thought. Unfortunatelly there might be problem with number of individuals in some stratums. I would have a case that in sample in stratum I've only 1 observation and in other sample 40 observations. I will try to connect stratums.  Thanks for answer.